# What is wrong with my code? Should I be adopting the method I found online?

Tags: c

Objective: Ask user for input height, and print pyramid

Code I wrote:

```
for(i = 1; i <= height; i++)
{
   for (j = height-1; j >= 1; j--)
    {
      printf ("#");
    }
      printf ("\n");
{
```

Code I found online:

```
for(i = height; i >= 1; i++)
{
   for (j = 1; j <=i; j++)
    {
      printf ("#");
    }
      printf ("\n");
{
```

It should look something like this:

```
###
##
#
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of what it should do?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica why do you say so?

Comment: Better to  cut/paste the code you ran as its less error prone.

Comment: Extreme: Both forms, when `height == INT_MAX` have _undefined behavior_ on overflow.  Neither form is C idiomatic.  I would use neither.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ooo interesting, thank you. I am a real beginner at coding, so I'm really just trying to understand the logic for the most basic of cases. Which logic would you say is better for this example, lets say it only takes input from 1-5?

Comment: Please post something that compiles, a [mcve], as there are too many unknowns to the problem for a quality answer.

Comment: The 'online' code you posted isn't right. It should be `i--`, not `i++`.

Answer (score 2):

Kinda like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int height = 7;
    
    char blocks[2*height];
    ((char*)memset(blocks, '#', 2*height-1))[2*height-1] = '\0';
    
    for(int i=0; i<height; ++i)
    {
        printf("%*.*s\n", height+i, 2*i+1, blocks);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Result:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5472KB
      #
     ###
    #####
   #######
  #########
 ###########
#############
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample output you provided:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int height = 7;
    
    char blocks[height+1];
    ((char*)memset(blocks, '#', height))[height] = '\0';
    
    for(int i=0; i<height; ++i)
    {
        printf("%.*s\n", height-i, blocks);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Result:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5520KB
#######
######
#####
####
###
##
#
```